# Collecting a range of keys from a dictionary

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, python-3.x, range

I am stumped. I have a Timesheet class that holds work days in a dictionary called self.timesheet with dates as the keys and hours, rate as values. I am trying to write a function that can show all the entries in a user defined range of dates.

for now lets assume the key dates are simple integers 20 - 25. i tried this and it didn't do anything at all. no errors, just nothing.

```
def show_days(self):
    date_from = input("From date: ")
    date_to = input("To date: ")
    t = self.timesheet

    for dates in t[date]:
        range(date_from, date to)
        print(dates)
```

I can see this doesn't look right , I feel I need *for dates in range(date_from, date_to)* but I can't figure how to get it to loop over the dictionary keys like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the range, then check if that key is in the dictionary:

```
for day in range(date_from, date_to + 1):
    if day in t:
        print day, t[day]
```

Note that the values produced by `range()` do *not* include the end point, so I used `date_to + 1` to ensure it is included anyway.

If your keys are *not* integers but, say, `datetime.date` objects, you'll have to construct some kind of loop with `datetime.timedelta()` to iterate over all dates between two values:

```
date = date_from = datetime.date(2012, 1, 15)
date_to = datetime.date(2012, 3, 12)

while date <= date_to:
    if date in t:
        print date, t[date]
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Great thanks! I have it working with ints and pprint. Now to get datetime involved...